# How to bundle services with android project

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, android-bundle

I'm trying to use google maps in my android application. Therefore, I have 2 projects. One is my android app and another will be the google-play-services. How can I export the apk so that it is bundled together with the google-play-services?

Comment: You did not import the Services lib? What else do you need to bundle?

Comment: have you add google play services as library to your project?

Comment: Yes i've imported it and i've added it as a library. If i didn't import it as a library it wouldn't work right? Anyways, when i install my app, the google-play-services is not installed together. Help please.

Comment: Basically my issue is this. I have a samsung device that is NOT installed with google play services. How can i include google play services in my apk so that they don't have to manually download? Is it possible?

Comment: did you add it to your build path or just as a library dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to bundle the actual Google Play services APK as part of your app. From the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure):

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>
> - A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and
>     includes Google Play Store. Or...
> - The Android emulator with an AVD that runs
>     the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

You can, however, check if Google Play services are available and do an action based on the result (in your case, link them to the store where they can download it) by calling `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure).